# I'm using a java thread pool, and I got an error I can't understand

Tags: java

```
<bean id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="6"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="6"/>
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="5"/>
    <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="120"/>
    <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="myThread_"/>
</bean>
```

---

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) context.getBean("threadPoolTaskExecutor");
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        list.add(i);
        if(6 == list.size()){
            doWork(list,executor);
            list.clear();
        }
    }

    if(list.size() > 0)
        doWork(list,executor);

    System.out.println("all work finished");

}

static void doWork(List<Integer> list,ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor){
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(list.size());
    for(final int i:list){
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    latch.countDown();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Above is my code. When I set `queueCapacity` 6 or larger than 6 it works well, but when `queueCapacity` is less than 6 the program will produce an error:

```
> Exception in thread "main"
> org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor
> [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1f7911b[Running, pool size =
> 6, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 5, completed tasks = 18]] did
> not accept task: com.my.service.test.Test$1@1de8526; nested exception
> is java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
> com.my.service.test.Test$1@1de8526 rejected from
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1f7911b[Running, pool size =
> 6, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 5, completed tasks = 18]    at
> org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:305)
>   at com.my.service.test.Test.doWork(Test.java:42)    at
> com.my.service.test.Test.main(Test.java:27)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
> com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
> com.my.service.test.Test$1@1de8526 rejected from
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1f7911b[Running, pool size =
> 6, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 5, completed tasks = 18]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
>   at
> org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:302)
>   ... 7 more
```

Who can tell me why, when I put a task to the thread pool, the poll first puts the task to workQueue?

Answer (score 18):

Rules for creating threads internally by Sun:

1. If the number of threads is less than the `corePoolSize`, create a new thread to run a new task.
2. If the number of threads is equal (or greater than) the `corePoolSize`, put the task into the queue.
3. If the queue is full, and the number of threads is less than the `maxPoolSize`, create a new thread to run tasks in.
4. If the queue is full, and the number of threads is greater than or equal to `maxPoolSize`, reject the task.

Your case is the last one where number of thread has reached to `maxPoolSize` i.e 6 and the queue is also full (number of task in queue is 5) so the task comes is rejected and gives `TaskRejectedException`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<property name="queueCapacity" value="5"/>
```

So the maximum ammount of "waiting" tasks to be executed is 5. Any futher submit performed before previous tasks are complete, will result in `TaskRejectException`

This information is also stored in exception itself

> [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1f7911b[Running, pool size =
>   6, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 5, completed tasks = 18]

Comment: but in my program ,there won't be more 6 task in the  thread pool at the same time.  And the pool won't  receive any task until  tasks in the pool have all finished.

Comment: Try `submit` insteed of `execute` besides. And as you said, there will be no more than 6 tasks, but the queue size is 5 not 6

Comment: when a pool receive a task,it will first put it to the queue?

Comment: It seams so due characteristic excetpion. Did you check the source code of `execute` method?.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your `queueCapacity`:

```
<property name="queueCapacity" value="500"/>
```